# Is it possible to have some kind of a group query that groups on the number in a column?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, count

I have a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Score"(
"Id" varchar primary key not null ,
"EnglishCount" int ,
"RomajiCount" int )
```

Is there a type of query that I could run that would show me:

```
   how many rows have EnglishCount = 0,
   how many rows have EnglishCount = 1,
   how many rows have EnglishCount = 2,
   how many rows have EnglishCount = 3,
   how many rows have EnglishCount = 4,
   etc ...
```

Here's the kind of output I am hoping to get:

```
Count    Instances
0        1
1        2
3        1
4        5
5        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `group by` clause to separate the result per distinct value of `EnglishCount` and then apply `count(*)` to each group:

```
SELECT   EnglishCount, COUNT(*)
FROM     Score
GROUP BY EnglishCount
```